# fontVariationSettings not found in ionic build

Tags: android, ionic-framework

Android build failed after android releases #june_17_2019

> AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found
>
> ionic info
>       @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
>       ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1
```

System:

```
Node  : v8.9.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this discussion https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25371

In particular the answer by shreyakupadhyay dated 30/07/19